# if else statement in a for loop to append to a list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, pyspark, append

I can't understand why the list doesn't append in pyspark. Can someone help look at my code?

```
import json

input_file = sc.textFile("data.json")

def extract_func(data):
    c_list = []
    neighborhoods = data.get('neighborhoods', None)

    for n in neighborhoods:
        if n == []:
            c_list.append('Unknown')
        else:
            c_list.append(n)

    return c_list
```

Example data entry:

```
{'attributes': {'Accepts Credit Cards': True,
 'city': 'Edinburgh',
 'name': 'Conan Doyle',
 'neighborhoods': [],
 'stars': 3.5,
 'state': 'EDH'}}
```

This example entry doesn't have a neighborhood shown, so I want to append 'unknown' to the list. Some other data entries have multiple neighborhoods, so I want to append them individually by the for loop.

When I run `dat = input_file.map(lambda line: json.loads(line))` followed by `dat = dat.flatMap(extract_func)`, it doesn't give me the `Unknown` neighborhood entries.

Being checking for hours, can't figure out what's wrong, what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the list doesn't append"? What's supposed to be appended to what? You're calling `data.get()` but data is not defined. What is `data` supposed to be? What is the `dat` variable you're referring to?

Comment: If `n` is iterating over a dict, it will be set to the keys of the dict, not the values.

Comment: In your `data` `neighborhoods` is a subkey of `attributes`, so you will have to get that first and `neighborhoods` from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if n == []:` will only be reached and evaluate to `True` if `neighborhoods` *contains* an empty list, but not when it's itself empty. You can simplify the code to:

```
neighborhoods = data.get("neighborhoods")
if neighborhoods:
    c_list = ["Unknown" if n == [] else n for n in neighborhoods]
else:
    c_list = ["Unknown"]
```

Or using a conditional expression:

```
c_list = (["Unknown" if n == [] else n for n in neighborhoods] if neighborhoods
          else ["Unknown"])
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the empty list problem! This is exactly where I was stuck.